# ordenar consulta MySQL con dos criterios

Tags: mysql

Buenas,

No encuentro la forma de hacer lo siguiente. Necesito hacer una consulta a una base de datos que me ordene primero con un criterio, y después de todos los resultados con este primer criterio, que vayan el resto y ordenador por la fecha de la última edición.

Para intentar aclarar un poco el problema. Es una tabla que carga todos los hilos de un foro. En el foro quiero que primero me muestre aquellos hilos que están "fijados", independientemente de la fecha de la última edición, y después el resto, ordenados por la fecha de la última edición.

Estoy intentando con este código pero no me devuelve nada:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE chincheta = 1 ORDER BY fecha_comentario) t comentarios WHERE foro = :foro AND subforo = :subforo AND en_que_hilo = :en_que_hilo AND chincheta = 0 ORDER BY fecha_edicion DESC LIMIT $inicio, $post_por_pagina");
$statement->execute(array(":foro" => $foro, ":subforo" => $subforo, ":en_que_hilo" => 0));
$todos_los_hilos = $statement->fetchAll();
```

No sé si es posible hacerlo...o tengo que hacer dos consultas distintas, de esa forma sí que sabría hacerlo, pero el tema de la paginación se complicaría, por eso quiero sacar todos de una sola consulta a ser posible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITO:

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE foro = :foro AND subforo = :subforo AND en_que_hilo = :en_que_hilo ORDER BY chincheta DESC, fecha_edicion DESC LIMIT $inicio, $post_por_pagina");
$statement->execute(array(":foro" => $foro, ":subforo" => $subforo, ":en_que_hilo" => 0));
$todos_los_hilos = $statement->fetchAll();
```

De esta forma se me muestran primero los hilos fijados y después el resto de hilos (bien hasta aquí), pero no me ordena los hilos por la fecha de la última edición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os muestro una imagen para intentar explicarlo mejor. El primer hilo que sale está bien, es el fijado y quiero que se me muestre antes que los que no están fijados, después van el resto de hilos, pero como veis no se ordenan, después del hilo fijado debería ir el hilo que está en 3º posición.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tus tablas? Aunque si quieres ordenar por dos campos puedes utilizar un ORDER BY combinado: `ORDER BY campo1, campo2`

Comment: Cuales hilos son los fijados? o a que te refieres con hilos fijados?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero He actualizado con una captura de la estructura de la tabla. Estoy probando también con los dos criterios que comentas, aunque de momento no lo he conseguido.

Comment: @Sergio1871 Con hilos fijados me refiero a que dentro del foro, habrá hilos que quiera que no sigan el orden normal del foro y que se puedan perder de vista. Bien como puede ser que abra un hilo de normas y quiero que esté en la primera posición siempre, por eso quiero  dar prioridad a los hilos que estén fijados.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo, quieres mostrar primero todos aquellos hilos que están "fijos" y todos aquellos que no están "fijados" se muestren por su última edición? No está muy clara esa parte, dime si te entendí bien

Comment: Pero en que campo esta lo del hilo? porque si es "en_que_hilo", todos están en el mismo dado que lo estás pasando en condición del WHERE

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Lo he solucionado finalmente con lo que me has comentado. Si quieres publica una respuesta y la doy como buena. Edito: Perdón, me falta ordenarlo por la fecha de edición, pensaba que sí que lo estaba ordenando.

Comment: @5frags Así es, primero los fijados y después el resto en función de la última edición.